# Postgresql join three table

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have an inventory database, and i need to calculate the quantity of products after each Buy or sell operation through my stock. So, i have three tables.The equation is like so :

```
(QtyInital +     (BuyQuantity(IN)  - SELLQUANTITY(OUT)
```

And Here is the schema of my three tables.

```
product(pid,name,qteInital,qteStock);
productInBuyFacture(baid,pid,qte,price,subtotal);
productInSellFacture(bsid,pid,qte,price,subtotal);
```

i want to calculate the current quantity of the stock via a trigger. I tried to do this via an SUB QUERYIES like so,

```
select ((select qteInital from product where id = 3) + 
(select qte from productInBuyFacture where pid = 3 ) - 
(select qte from productInSellFacture where pid = 3) as currentQuantity ;
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need summation and to fix the parentheses so they balance:

```
select ((select coalesce(sum(qteInital), 0) from product where id = 3) + 
        (select coalesce(sum(qte), 0) from productInBuyFacture where pid = 3 ) - 
        (select coalesce(sum(qte), 0) from productInSellFacture where pid = 3)
       ) as currentQuantity ;
```

The `coalesce()` is to prevent a problem with non-matches.  A `NULL` in an arithmetic expression will generally cause the entire expression to return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with explicit join:

```
SELECT pro.pid, pro.QtyInital, COALESCE(SUM(buy.qte), 0) AS buyqty, COALESCE(SUM(sell.qte), 0) AS sellqty
FROM product AS pro
LEFT JOIN productInBuyFacture AS buy
ON pro.pid = buy.pid
LEFT JOIN productInSellFacture AS sell
ON pro.pid = sell.pid
GROUP BY pro.pid, pro.QtyInital
```